# Override GetItemCheckState() from a checklistbox

Tags: c#, overriding, checkedlistbox

Is there any way to override `GetItemCheckState(i)` from CheckedListBox? I'm trying to make a class to have a custom CheckedListBox that works the exact same, but when I call `GetItemCheckState(i)` instead of returning string `Checked` or `Unchecked` I want it to return bool `true` or `false`.
Visual Studio tells me that the override modifier is not valid for this item, is there any way around this?

[Edit] I found a workaround, but I'm not sure if it will cause some sort of issue and I dunno if it's the most elegant solution, so almost same question still, there is a better workaround for this?

What I did:

```
public class ExCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
    {

        public bool GetItemCheckState2(int index)
        {
            string aux = (this.GetItemCheckState(index)).ToString();
            if(aux == "Checked")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(aux == "Unchecked")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Amy, can you help me out by letting me know what technology you are using ? Windows Forms, WPF ASP.net, Asp.netcore, xamarin ? A link to the particular checkbox you are using on MSDN would be very helpful

Comment: C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Windows Forms on Visual Studio

Comment: It doesn't return the string "Checked" / "Unchecked".  YOU are creating the string by calling `ToString()`.  It would be more elegant to use the [`CheckState` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkstate?view=net-5.0) as intended.  Conversion to bool can be as simple as `bool b = GetItemCheckState(index) != CheckState.Unchecked;`

Comment: `GetItemChecked(#)` returns a bool.  `GetItemCheckState(#)` returns an enumeration.

Comment: So I can `method(list.GetItemCheckState(0) != CheckState.Unchecked);` and the method will recieve the bool correctly?

Comment: or .. just .. use .. `GetItemChecked`  It already does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apparently something was wrong with my project/visual studio cuz that `GetItemChecked` method wasn't showing up yesterday, so I assumed it would only be a thing in Checkbox instead of CheckListBox, today I had to reboot Visual Studio like twice to get it to load the methods for most objects, even things like `MessageBox.Show("");` wasn't loading. This solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LarsTech and Ben Voigt said, `GetItemChecked(#)` or `GetItemCheckState(index) != CheckState.Unchecked;` solves my issue.